# Given a Git revision, how can I find the tags it sits between?

Tags: git

Given a revision, say `fed3245`, how can I find the tags `3.3` and `3.3.1` that come before and after `fed3245`?

Answer (score 1):

You can find all tags before the revision by the following command:

```
git tag --contains fed3245
```

Similarly, the tags after that revision by:

```
git tag --no-contains fed3245
```

Comment: I think this is a good idea but needs some fixes: `--contains` gets all tags containing i.e. after the rev, and to get all ancestor tags you want `--merged fed3245`. You could then feed them all to `git log --no-walk --stdin --pretty=%D` and take the last contains and the first merged.

Answer (score 1):

```
git describe --abbrev=0 --contains fed3245 
git describe --abbrev=0 $_
```

`git describe` by default works only off annotated tags, to control what refs it looks at see its docs.  Edit: I see the no-abbrev logic seems a little bugged with `--contains`, you'll have to strip the ancestry refs, brute force workaround is

```
c=`git describe --abbrev=0 --contains fed3245`; echo ${c%%[~^]*}
git describe --abbrev=0 fed3245
```